# How to check if an entry exists or not in an C# List with the Find Method

Tags: c#, linq, list

I use a C# List with the Find method the following way:

```
Tag searchResult = tags.Find(x => x.TagId.Equals(tag));
```

The list holds the "struct Tag", now my problem is how can I check if the tag entry exists in the list.

Under the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/x0b5b5bc(v=vs.110).aspx) side, I found the following:

- If nothing could be found then "the default value for type T" will be
  returned.

So I tried the following:

```
if(default(Tag) == searchResult ){}
```

But this dosen't work because of the Error: " Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type "

What do I wrong?

Comment: Try `if (searchResult  == null) {}`

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc(v=vs.110).aspx english link

Comment: Note, regarding the error you're getting, it's likely because you haven't actually specified the `==` (and `!=`) operator overloads. (See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx for guidelines implementing these operators) These operators aren't automatically implemented for value types. Even if you did though, I wouldn't recommend comparing against `default(Tag)` because you wouldn't be able to discern between a not found value (`default`) and an found value which happened to have the same values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `Tag` is a `struct`, I wouldn't recommend testing against `default(Tag)` anyway as you wouldn't know whether or not you didn't find a `Tag` or happened to find `Tag` that has the same default/empty values as a `default(Tag)`.

Short of doing two queries (An `.Any()` followed by a `.First()`) that share the same search predicate, your best bet might be rolling your own method. Perhaps an extension method that returns a `Nullable<T>` which you can use for any `struct`:

```
public static T? FirstOrNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> predicate) where T : struct
{
    foreach(var item in items)
    {
        if (predicate(item))
            return item;
    }

    return null;
}
```

With usage like:

```
Tag? searchResult = tags.FirstOrNull(x => x.TagId.Equals(tag));
if (searchResult != null)
{
    //do something with your search result
}
```

Of course, at this point it's like any standard `Nullable<Tag>` (or `Tag?`) so you can use the `.HasValue`, `.Value`, and `.GetValueOrDefault()` members as you wish.

---

EDIT: Rereading your question, it seems you are asking strictly to check if the item exists, not to actually retrieve it. If however, you really plan to retrieve it if it exists and do something with that tag, then you'll either have to do two searches (first to check, second to retrieve) or use a method like this.

Answer (score 5):

A couple of approaches.

You can use `Enumerable.Any()`:

```
if (tags.Any(x => x.TagId.Equals(tag)))
{
    // There's a match.
}
```

Or if you want to actually find the relevant tag, use `Enumerable.FirstOrDefault`:

```
var tag = tags.FirstOrDefault(x => x.TagId.Equals(tag));
if (tag != null) 
{
    // There exists a tag.
}
```

Comment: The question specified that `Tag` was a `struct`, so I don't think a `FirstOrDefault` and check against `null` would work. (It would return a default/empty instance of `Tag`). I think you'd have to use `.Any()` first or roll your own helper method that would return a `Nullable<T>` or a "Try" type of method that would return a `true/false` and `out` the found variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want it check if the item exists you can use Contains() from System.Linq :

```
bool exists = tags.Contains(tag);
```

This will use structural equality to compare your tag. So in other words all fields on the Tag need to be equal (not just the id). You can use the overload to pass in your own IEqualityComparer if you want to specify exactly how equality should be determined.